# Populate form with customer data, if known

Tags: html, magento, php

I am using Magento, and I have a form.html that asks for customer data. When the customer is logged in, I want to prepopulate the relevant fields with known data.
I have used the following constructs, but none work.
The listing begins with the (commented out) line that just asks for filling in, then my two modifications, the first one commented out. Both are not working. What's wrong?

```
<!--<td valign="top"><input maxlength="30" name="name" size="20" type="text"></td>-->
<!--<td valign="top"><echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName();></td>-->
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost("name");?>" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first modification (second line commented out) won't work because you haven't wrapped the PHP in its tags.

Try writing a statement to check if the customer is logged in.

```
<?php
     if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) :
        //Write out the customer's full name
        echo Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName();
     else :
        echo 'Customer not logged in';
     endif;
?>
```

If there is still no value being returned it might be because you haven't got the customer's session ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     $customer = new Varien_Object();
     if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
       $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
     }
?>


<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $customer->getData('name') ?>" />
</td>
```